Third Term Results Not Displaying in Final Output Despite Presence in Array
I’m having an issue with displaying exam subjects and results for the third term in my PHP application. First Term and Second Term displays just fine but the Third term is not displaying. All three terms are supposed to display on the same page as a single result card with student's scores and positions. The subjects and results data for third term are correctly populated in an array, but they are not showing up in the final output.
Here’s a brief overview of what I’m trying to achieve:

Data Retrieval:
I am retrieving exam subjects and results for the third term from the database. The data seems to be correctly fetched as I can see it in the array.

Data Structure:
The data for the third term subjects is structured as follows:




Exam Subjects for THIRD TERM: Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 15687
            [school_id] => 2
            [exam_id] => 7
            [class_id] => 1
            [section_id] => 8
            [subject_id] => 74
            [academic_year_id] => 1
            [student_id] => 149
            [grade_id] => 1
            [written_mark] => 20
            [written_obtain] => 18
            [tutorial_mark] => 0
            [tutorial_obtain] => 0
            [practical_mark] => 40
            [practical_obtain] => 26
            [viva_mark] => 40
            [viva_obtain] => 30
            [exam_total_mark] => 100
            [obtain_total_mark] => 74
            [remark] => Excellent!
            [status] => 1
            [created_at] => 2024-08-03 08:15:49
            [modified_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [created_by] => 314
            [modified_by] => 0
            [subject] => BUSINESS STUDIES
            [point] => 5.00
            [name] => A
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 15768
            [school_id] => 2
            [exam_id] => 7
            [class_id] => 1
            [section_id] => 8
            [subject_id] => 62
            [academic_year_id] => 1
            [student_id] => 149
            [grade_id] => 1
            [written_mark] => 20
            [written_obtain] => 16
            [tutorial_mark] => 0
            [tutorial_obtain] => 18
            [practical_mark] => 40
            [practical_obtain] => 15
            [viva_mark] => 40
            [viva_obtain] => 37
            [exam_total_mark] => 100
            [obtain_total_mark] => 86
            [remark] => Excellent!
            [status] => 1
            [created_at] => 2024-08-03 08:13:37
            [modified_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [created_by] => 314
            [modified_by] => 0
            [subject] => BASIC SCIENCE
            [point] => 5.00
            [name] => A
        )
   ...
)





<!-- HTML/PHP code to generate the results table -->
<table id="datatable-responsive" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2">Sl. No.</th>
            <th rowspan="2">Subject</th>
            <th colspan="2">Written</th>
            <th colspan="2">Tutorial</th>
            <th colspan="2">Practical</th>
            <th colspan="2">Viva</th>
            <th colspan="2">Total</th>
            <th rowspan="2">Letter Grade</th>
            <th rowspan="2">Grade Point</th>
            <th rowspan="2">Lowest</th>
            <th rowspan="2">Height</th>
            <th rowspan="2">Position</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Mark</th>
            <th>Obtain</th>
            <th>Mark</th>
            <th>Obtain</th>
            <th>Mark</th>
            <th>Obtain</th>
            <th>Mark</th>
            <th>Obtain</th>
            <th>Mark</th>
            <th>Obtain</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="fn_mark">
        <?php if (isset($exams) && !empty($exams)) { ?>
            <?php foreach($exams as $ex) { ?>
                <tr style="background: #f9f9f9;">
                    <th colspan="17"><?php echo $ex->title; ?></th>
                </tr>
                <?php
                $exam_subjects = get_subject_list($school_id, $academic_year_id, $ex->id, $class_id, $section_id, $student_id);
                if (isset($exam_subjects) && !empty($exam_subjects)) {
                    foreach ($exam_subjects as $obj) {
                        $exam = get_exam_result($school_id, $ex->id, $student_id, $academic_year_id, $class_id, $section_id);
                        if(@$exam->name == '') { continue; }
                        $lh = get_lowet_height_mark($school_id, $academic_year_id, $ex->id, $class_id, $section_id, $obj->subject_id );
                        $position = get_position_in_subject($school_id, $academic_year_id, $ex->id, $class_id, $section_id, $obj->subject_id, $obj->obtain_total_mark);
                        ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $count++; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo ucfirst($obj->subject); ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $obj->written_mark; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $obj->written_obtain; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $obj->tutorial_mark; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $obj->tutorial_obtain; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $obj->practical_mark; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $obj->practical_obtain; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $obj->viva_mark; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $obj->viva_obtain; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $obj->exam_total_mark; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $obj->obtain_total_mark; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $obj->name; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $obj->point; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $lh->lowest; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $lh->height; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $position; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php } ?>
                <?php } else { ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="17" align="center">No data found</td>
                    </tr>
                <?php } ?>
            <?php } ?>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="17" align="center">No data found</td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>



Issue:
Despite the subjects for third term being correctly populated in the array, they are not showing up in the HTML output as First and Second term are. The array seems fine when printed, but the data does not appear where expected.
Can anyone provide insights or suggestions on what might be causing the third term results to not display?
I've tried the following:

Verified the structure of $examSubjects and $exams. Seems fine
Added debugging statements to check the array content before the loop

I was expecting the data for third term to be missing, it was present in the array, however, it does not display in the HTML output.


Can you provide more code? Currently we can see the structure of your array but have no idea how you're using it to generate the HTML - that is most likely where the issue is.

Please always present sample array data as copy-pasted var_export() text.  Please never say "Thank you" or "Any help would be appreciated".  Your [mcve] should be minimal, complete, and well-formatted.

@mickmackusa noted.

Are there any errors in your logs? If you have errors disabled, it would be best to re-enable them for troubleshooting. If an error occurred and it stopped the execution, you could check the raw output by viewing the page source - if it cut off part way through a row, it most likely stopped due to an error/exception. Aside from that, the code seems like it should work, but we also do not know the structure of all variables so it's hard to say anything for certain

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
